# Set window icon inside QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I understand that you can set the QML window icon using .setWindowIcon(QIcon) after creating the QGuiApplication object. However I have multiple windows created in QML and I want to set an icon to a window inside from QML for example inside:

```
Window {
    id: settings
    width: 300
    height: 300
    title: qsTr("Settings")
    flags: Qt.Window
    visible: false
    // Set window icon here...
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I have researched about this and I cannot find anything related to this.

Comment: I guess it's impossible in QML. The only way I see to is cast the window instance to `QWindow` and set an icon using `QWindow::setIcon`, in C++ of course.

Comment: I would imagine that you could create a QML interface that calls C++ code. It would not be hard to create a QObject that sets the icon. And that object could be exposed to QML. I would try it out if I had time, but it would be something like: WindowIcon { source: “qrc:/myicon.png” }